# Threading behavior of SameQ vs. Equal

Tags: list-manipulation, evaluation

I ran into unexpected behavior in my code based on an errant assumption. Namely, I thought that:

```
ClearAll[aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff];
Thread[Equal[{aa, bb, cc}, {dd, ee, ff}]]
Thread[SameQ[{aa, bb, cc}, {dd, ee, ff}]]
```

would result in:

```
{aa == dd, bb == ee, cc == ff}
{False, False, False}
```

What I get instead is:

```
{aa == dd, bb == ee, cc == ff}
False
```

Which I can argue makes sense, since the lists aren't equivalent. But why doesn't `Thread` work? What's the precedence argument here? How can I get the answer I want (`{False, False, False}`) from a similar construct?

Comment: To get `{False,False,False}` you can use `MapThread[SameQ, {{aa, bb, cc}, {dd, ee, ff}}]`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Thread` doesn't hold its arguments. You can check its attributes.

So, before doing any threading, it evaluates its arguments.

Now, understanding the behaviour you describe requires understanding the difference between `Equal` and `SameQ`. `Equal` is meant for math reasoning. For expressing an equality, which might involve a variable that at the time you don't yet know it's value. So, for example, `x==8` returns unevaluated if `x` isn't defined.

`SameQ` however is a predicate. It will always return either `True` or `False` if the constructs are exactly the same (after evaluation).

So, `Thread[SameQ[{aa, bb, cc}, {dd, ee, ff}]]` -> `Thread[False]`-> `False`

One can see this by running (thanks @rcollyer)

```
Trace[Thread[SameQ[{aa, bb, cc}, {dd, ee, ff}]], 
 TraceInternal -> True]

Out[1] = {{{aa, bb, cc} === {dd, ee, ff}, False}, Thread[False], False}
```

If you want to thread `SameQ` without evaluation, just use `Unevaluated`

```
Thread[Unevaluated@SameQ[{aa, bb, cc}, {dd, ee, ff}]]

{False, False, False}
```

Another construction that gives the result you want is the one suggested by @kguler in his comment and supported by @rcoller and his upvoters: `MapThread`. I'd suggest you search the docs if you don't know it

```
MapThread[SameQ, {{aa, bb, cc}, {dd, ee, ff}}]
```

Comment: Or, `MapThread`, fewer characters required. :)

Comment: Yeah... I personally prefer the looks of the prefix notation `Thread@Unevaluated@SameQ[{aa, bb, cc}, {dd, ee, ff}]`

Comment: Whatever works.

Comment: I meant to write `Thread@Unevaluated@({aa, bb, cc}==={dd, ee, ff})`

Comment: Oops, I just assumed Thread held things. Sure enough though, `Attributes[Thread]=={Protected}`... Thanks for the suggestions on how to get around that!

Answer (score 11):

I use `Part` for this sort of thing.

```
data = Transpose[{{aa, bb, cc}, {dd, ee, ff}}]
{{aa, dd}, {bb, ee}, {cc, ff}}
```

Now change the heads:

```
data[[All, 0]] = Equal;
data
{aa == dd, bb == ee, cc == ff}
```

and:

```
data[[All, 0]] = SameQ;
data
{False, False, False}
```

Comment: I like the use of the 0th part to replace the head :)

Comment: I only started using it a couple of months ago but now use it a fair bit due to it being nice and concise.

Comment: An interesting replacement for `Equal @@@ data`, although in this case, I think `Apply` wins in character count. But, definitely something to keep in mind when working with deeper nesting.