# Using 0 to create new columns in a list with Part

Tags: list-manipulation

I just discovered a nice way to create intermediary columns in a list, and I would like to know if I can have some problem with it. It Works like this:

Imagine I have this list, 5x3:

```
SeedRandom[0]
list=RandomInteger[100,{5,3}]
```

Now I want to add a new blank column after position 1. I can use 0 for that, as you can see:

```
list=list[[All,{1,0,2,3}]]
list[[All,2]]=100
list
```

> {{83, 100, 66, 4}, {21, 100, 71, 67}, {16, 100, 67, 76}, {28, 100, 21,
>   43}, {17, 100, 46, 53}}

Using `0` put List as start element of the new column.

**Question:**
Can I have some problem in doing that way? I can't see any. And it appears to work in a nice speed.

Comment: is your method faster than using Insert? `SeedRandom[0];
list = RandomInteger[100, {5, 3}];
list = Transpose@Insert[Transpose[list], list[[All, 2]], 2]`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't see any problem with this, other than unpacking as WReach beat me to writing.  Part zero is simply the head of the expression, in this case the rows, here `List`.  As another example:

```
x = foo[a[1, 2], b[3, 4], c[5, 6]];

x[[All, {1, 0, 2}]]
```

> ```
> foo[a[1, a, 2], b[3, b, 4], c[5, c, 6]]
> ```

As long as you understand this and accept what obfuscation it entails it seems reasonable.  Note that you aren't actually *inserting* a column but rather reconstructing the entire array.

---

Purely parenthetically, and not that I propose ever using such a thing, but for fun here's another way to insert a column using part zero:

```
SeedRandom[0]
list = RandomInteger[100, {5, 3}];

list[[All, 0]] = {#, 7, ##2} &;

list
```

> ```
> {{83, 7, 66, 4},
>  {21, 7, 71, 67},
>  {16, 7, 67, 76},
>  {28, 7, 21, 43},
>  {17, 7, 46, 53}}
> ```

Hey, if we're going for weird I can code with the best of them. :^)

Comment: Now I want to understand what kind of Black Mathic is this! How is this pure function actually working? Any link? +1

Comment: @Murta I added that with the hope of causing people to pause and give a second thought to "part zero" and I think it worked. :-)  If we *replace* the heads of the rows (`List`) with the function we get e.g. `{#, 7, ##2} &[83, 66, 4]` and I think you can probably work out the rest for yourself.

Comment: A New Kind of Map :)

Comment: Very interesting to know.

Comment: @WReach Probably *A New Kind of `Apply`* would be more correct since we replace `Head`s here and `Apply` is the function which replaces `Head`s.

Comment: @WReach Before I get (more?) credit that isn't due **this isn't my trick; I learned it from Mike Honeychurch**: [(4399)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4399/121)

Comment: I am trying to set list[[;; , 2]] = {a, b, c, d, e} but it did not work in your method and works in the OP method. check out this also list[[;; , 4]] = {a, b, c, d, e}.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Okay, okay...  _A New Kind of Map/Apply_ = _A New Kind of Maple_  ;D

Answer (score 14):

Neat trick.

One disadvantage I see to this approach is that it unpacks a packed array:

```
Needs["Developer`"]

SeedRandom[0]
list = RandomInteger[100, {5, 3}]
list // PackedArrayQ
(* True *)

list[[All, {1, 0, 2, 3}]] // PackedArrayQ
(* False *)
```

This is because the symbol `List` is being repeatedly inserted into the new column.  If we choose to populate the new column from another arbitrarily selected column, the array will remain packed:

```
list[[All, {1, 1, 2, 3}]] // PackedArrayQ
(* True *)
```

Since we are going to overwrite the new column anyway, it doesn't matter what values we write into it.

Having said all that, the use of zero stands out and it could be a nice idiom if array packing is not essential to the situation.

Comment: Interesting point about PackedArrays. It would be nice if we could just use `Null` as `list[[All, {1, Null, 2, 3}]]`, and keep it packed but it's not possible. Tks +1

Answer (score 5):

I am uncertain why it is interesting to create the "blank" column with Part 0 rather than with any other Part.  If I understand the problem, it is really to add a column at a location 2 and then make an assignment to that new column, so it is really irrelevant what the contents of the new column are. If that is correct, then you could

```
SeedRandom[0] 
list2d = RandomInteger[100, {5, 3}]
col = ConstantArray[100, 5]
MapThread[Insert[#1, #2, 2] &, {list2d, col}]  (* ht Mark *)
```

Or if you wanted to stick with your approach but less oddly, you could

```
newlist2d = list2d[[All, {1, 1, 2, 3}]]
newlist2d[[All, 2]] = 100
```