# Why does my threaded function need to be substituted?

Tags: list-manipulation

In [my code](https://github.com/orome/gchq-puzzles/tree/45dfa1ce161aa3b7c8d45d434f524b3c31a908a6) I have

```
With[
 {
  rowCells=(genCells[#]&/@genSpecs[#])&/@clueRows,
  colCells=(genCells[#]&/@genSpecs[#])&/@clueCols
 },
 While[Not@isDone@Flatten@constraintTable,
    constraintTable=(Thread[f[rowCells,constraintTable]]/.f-> constraintStrip);
    constraintTable=(Thread[f[colCells,constraintTable\[Transpose]]]
                     /.f-> constraintStrip)\[Transpose];
 ]
]
```

but when I attempt to replace the substitutions for `f` with

```
With[
  {
   rowCells=(genCells[#]&/@genSpecs[#])&/@clueRows,
   colCells=(genCells[#]&/@genSpecs[#])&/@clueCols
  },
  While[Not@isDone@Flatten@constraintTable,
    constraintTable=(Thread[constraintStrip[rowCells,constraintTable]]);
    constraintTable=(Thread[constraintStrip[colCells,constraintTable\[Transpose]]]
                       /.f-> constraintStrip)\[Transpose];
  ]
]
```

I get

```
Transpose::nmtx: The first two levels of {Transpose[0],Transpose[0],Transpose[0],Transpose[0],Transpose[0],Transpose[0],Transpose[0],Transpose[0],Transpose[0],Transpose[0],Transpose[0],Transpose[0],Transpose[0],Transpose[0],Transpose[0],Transpose[0],Transpose[0],Transpose[0],Transpose[0],Transpose[0],Transpose[0],Transpose[0],Transpose[0],Transpose[0],Transpose[0]} cannot be transposed. >>
Transpose::nmtx: "The first two levels of {Transpose[],Transpose[],Transpose[],Transpose[],Transpose[],Transpose[],Transpose[],Transpose[],Transpose[],Transpose[],Transpose[],Transpose[],Transpose[],Transpose[],Transpose[],Transpose[],Transpose[],Transpose[],Transpose[],Transpose[],Transpose[],Transpose[],Transpose[],Transpose[],Transpose[]} cannot be transposed. \!\(\*ButtonBox[\">>\",
```

Why do I need to substitute in this way? How can avoid having to do so?

---

I have a similar issue with

```
showTable[t_]:=
Grid[
  Join[
    Join[
      ConstantArray["",{9,9},(Style[#,Bold]&/@PadLeft[#,9,""]&/@clueCols)]\[Transpose],
      (Thread[f[(Style[#,Bold]&/@PadLeft[#,9,""]&/@clueRows),
                (t/.cellGraphics)
               ]
    ]/.f->Join)
   ], 
   gridSpecs
];
```

where a substitution is also required in `Thread` to avoid errors.

Comment: `Thread` evaluates its argument before threading, so perhaps the problem comes from evaluating `constraintStrip[rowCells,constraintTable]`.

Comment: @SimonWoods: How can it thread over something if it evaluates the whole thing first?

Comment: For many things that's no problem: `Thread[{a,b}->{1,2}` yields `{a->1,b->2}`, which is quite useful.

Comment: If that *is* the source of the problem, the question is essentially a duplicate of [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85279/862)

Comment: You could `Inactivate` f.

Comment: @SimonWoods: And weirdly, `(MapThread[constraintStrip, {rowCells,constraintTable}])`, which the documentation says is the same thing, works fine.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: I must be missing something. I'm trying to thread `constraintStrip` over the arguments given; the given arguments themselves don't make sense for `constraintStrip`, so evaluating it wouldn't work.

Comment: The MapThread [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html) contains an example of the difference - *Properties & Relations*, fourth example.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius You have constrainStrip defined as a function of two variables and since you provide it with two it evaluates. `f` is undefined, doesn't evaluate and can then be threaded.

Comment: @SimonWoods: I guess I don't understand. How can even the third "basic example" in the `Thread` docs work? `Thread[f[{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}]]` can't work if `f` does't take lists arguments, though `f[a,x]`, etc. certainly can. What am I missing. And if the objective is to produce a list of such values (as in the docs, `{f[a,x], f[b,y], f[c,z]}`, isn't that what `Thread` is for?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: Wow, this is messed up: `Thread[{1,2,3}=={1,2,3}]` is `True`, but  `Thread[{1,2,3}=={1,c,3}]` is `{True, False, True}` unless is defined, say as `c=2`, in which case it's `True`. So the whole **structure** of the result — in fact, *whether any threading even takes place* — depends on whether all the components of the arguments can be fully evaluated. Talk about side effects!

Comment: It's not messed up, `{1,2,3}=={1,2,3}` evaluates to `True` - what do you think the result of `Thread[True]` should be?

Comment: There have been a few discussions about this. One that I could find is [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4390/threading-behavior-of-sameq-vs-equals) but there should be more.

Comment: @SimonWoods: That's not what's messed up. What's messed up is that whether `Thread` actually threads is contingent on whether every component of the arguments it's meant to thread over can be fully evaluated; if they can, threading will not happen.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: Yes, good link. `MapThread` is clearly what I should be using, `Thread` is clearly some other nutty thing that makes no sense.

Comment: I find Thread quite useful. In fact I use it quite a lot to make lists of rules needed to create Associations or Dispatch tables.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: Understood. But the question isn't whether uses can be found, it's [why have `Thread` provide such uses by not threading](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102104/37) (essentially as a side effect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid the substitution, it might be more "elegant" to use MapThread:

```
MapThread[Join, {colCells, constraintTable\[Transpose]}]
```

This works like Thread, but Join directly operates on the right arguments.

Comment: Yes, `MapThread` gives the expected behavior, [but why have `Thread` behave this way at all](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102104/37)?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Beacause Thread has not attributes like HoldAll and the like, so it first evaluates its arguments, as you can see evaluating Thread[(Print["f"]; f)[(Print["a"]; {a1, a2, a3}), (Print["b"]; {b1, b2, b3})]]. This prints "f", "a" and "b" and then threads f over the two list.

Comment: But why have `Thread` do that? Why have `Thread` designed to not thread in some cases.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius, the error comes from the effect of Join, not from from the behavior of Thread: when Join evaluates its arguments (before Thread acts, since the evaluations start from the leaves of the expression tree) it produces a single list, with the wrong shape for Thread. The reason why Thread is not holding it's argument should be explained by MMA designers.

Comment: I don't think `Join` comes into play in the first case though, where `f` is `constraintStrip`.