# Why doesn't Thread always thread?

Tags: list-manipulation

What is the rationale for `Thread` not threading as a side effect if the arguments of the function to be threaded can be fully evaluated?

For example,

```
ClearAll[b];
Thread[{1,2,3}=={1,b,3}]
```

gives (threading)

```
{True,2==b,True}
```

But

```
ClearAll[b];
b=2;
Thread[{1,2,3}=={1,b,3}]
```

gives (no threading, and a completely different type of result)

```
True
```

And

```
ClearAll[b];
Thread[{1,2,3}=={1,b,3}]/.b->2
```

gives

```
{True,True,True}
```

What's the purpose of the behavior? Shouldn't `Thread` always *thread*?

---

Note: the question is how the comes about ("`Thread` evaluates its arguments"); but why it makes sense to do this? Why make whether threading actually happens contingent on the state of arguments.

Comment: I think this was answered in your earlier post. The argument is evaluated prior to threading and returns True. Using  `Trace`  will illuminate the internal processing.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch: No. That's not the question. It's about what purpose that serves (specifically why have `Thread` not thread, as a side effect), not how it comes about; see the question.

Comment: `Thread` is *always* threading. However you see something different to what you want because arguments are evaluated prior to threading. There is no `HoldFirst` or similar attribute.

Comment: @OleksandrR.: As `MapThread`.

Comment: Surely you have enough _Mathematica_ experience to know, when using a built-in function, you must keep in mind how and when its arguments are evaluated. In particular, for functions that follow the standard evaluation rules, you must keep in mind that all arguments get fully evaluated before the function body sees them.

Comment: @m_goldberg: Yes, but there are enough exceptions that its confusing. The issue is really from moving back and fourth among languages. Mathematica has some misleading (not bad, just misleading) features. I keep having to remind myself that its all just *pattern matching*, and that what look like functions aren't functions and what look like types aren't types.

Comment: Frequent use of `??` or `Attributes` is highly recommended.

Comment: This is described under [Possible issues](http://wolfram.com/xid/0y791e-fpnhwv) on the Thread help page.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: Understood. I think this question got off on the wrong foot. Chip Hurst fortunately understood what the issue was and how to address it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mathematica evaluates subexpressions in a bottom up fashion:

```
Trace[Thread[{1, 2, 3} == {1, 2, 3}]]
```

> ```
> {{{1,2,3}=={1,2,3},True},Thread[True],True}
> ```

This means by the time `Thread` is being applied, it's argument is already `True`.

One way around this is to use `Unevaluated`.

```
Thread[Unevaluated[{1, 2, 3} == {1, 2, 3}]]
```

> ```
> {True, True, True}
> ```

### Edit

If `Thread` were to have some sort of `HoldFirst` attribute, it might not be as well defined as you might think.

The question is, how much partial evaluation is allowed?

1. If no partial evaluation is allowed, then

   ```
   a = {1, 2, 3}; b = {x, y, z}; Thread[a == b]
   ```

would return `a == b`, since the depths of the unevaluated `a` and `b` are 0.

2. Suppose `h[a, b]` is the input, and it evaluates `h`, `a`, and `b` but doesn't evaluate their composition. Then

   ```
   Thread[{1, 2, 3} == {x, y, z} /. {x -> 1}]
   ```

would not work as expected.

So the moral here is it's a bit trickier than one might think, and to account for a held attribute, one would need to often do tricks like

```
Thread[#]&[expr]
```

or

```
With[{e = expr}, Thread[e]]
```

which makes code messier.

Comment: The question isn't how the behavior comes about, it's what purpose that behavior serves. Why should `Thread` be designed to sometimes thread, and sometimes not thread over it's arguments. Especially since whether it does or not is dependent on what happens to be defined at the time in its context.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius See my edit. Let me know if you agree with this or not. It's partially gut feelings on my part.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius `Thread` is *always* threading. However you see something different to what you want because arguments are evaluated prior to threading. There is no `HoldFirst` or similar attribute.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch: Not really. If it evaluates its arguments its not threading; see `MapThread`.

Comment: @ChipHurst: What about `MapThread`. That behaves as expected but doesn't have these issues. Am I missing something about how that works by comparison?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius no point in circular discussion. Examine the `Trace` and the `Attributes` and you must conclude that it is threading and behaving as expected. If an expression cannot be threaded, e.g. `Thread[True]` then what do you expect to occur?

Comment: `MapThread` squelches some auto evaluation: `MapThread[Equal, {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}]`. This choice of syntax does a good job at preventing some auto evaluation because the head `List` is inert. A better example is `Thread[SameQ[list1, list2]]` will *always* return `True` or `False`, whereas `MapThread[SameQ, {list1, list2}]` will *always* return a list.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch: So why have a circular discussion when it could be avoided by attempting to answer the question? `Thread[f[{a,b,c},{1,2,3}]]` threads if the result is `{f[a,1],f[b,2],f[3,c]}`. But `Thread` sometimes does not do that, and whether it does depends on whether `a`, `b`, `c` and `f` can be evaluated. That's the phenomenon that seems odd (at least coming from a better organized language like, say Haskell). (How `Thread[True]` evaluates is irrelevant; what's relevant is why the argument to `Thread` is allowed to become `True` when it was, say `f[{a,b,c},{1,2,3}]`.)

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius It is circular because an explanation has been provided (also in your other recent question). There is no `HoldFirst` attribute. Therefore you are attempting to do `Thread[True]` which returns `True`. If you can show an example where `Thread` does not actually attempt to thread then I will comment further but as we have seen your examples do not show that.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch: What do you mean by "there is no `HoldFirst` attribute? The question (and what is meant by "doesn't thread") should be clear. What does `MapThread` do differently? Are you saying it is *impossible to design* `Thread[f[{a,b,c},{1,2,3}]]` so that it works like `MapThread[f, {{a,b,c},{1,2,3}}]` (as the docs actually sort of imply it does)? If that's the case, it may be the answer to the question.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius `MapThread[f, {{a, b, c}, {1, 2, 3}}]` does not literally contain `f[{a, b, c}, {1, 2, 3}]`, which consequently is not a possible result of evaluation no matter what attributes `MapThread` has. It's as simple as that.

Comment: @OleksandrR.: That's clear. But does that mean it is impossible to make `Thread` behave like `MapThread`. If so, that may the answer. If not, the question remains: why choose not to?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius no, of course it's not impossible. But it's not the way *Mathematica*'s evaluation sequence normally works. You're perfectly free to circumvent the ordinary sequence of evaluation if that's what you want in a given case, but I don't see why this ought to be the default especially for `Thread`.

Comment: @OleksandrR. @raxacoricofallapatorius and the point of my answer is to show there's always going to be some hiccups in any implementation. I think the best example is actually `x = {1, 2, 3} == {a, b, c}; heldThread[x]`. This will return `{1, 2, 3} == {a, b, c}`, which shows a `Thread` that holds it's inputs to prevent evaluation will ultimately produce unwanted results too.

Comment: @ChipHurst: That's a good point. And the right thing to focus on here. In your example `Thread[x]` does what I (stubbornly) want, but there's no way to put `MapThread` and `x` together to get that outcome. (It comes down to terrible documentation really; but it's not the first time).

Comment: Yes, I agree. I thought of the same example as a problematic case. There are other ways to do it, of course--`Block`ing or substitution of the `Head`, for example, to avoid interference from `Listable`. Still, I don't really see why such non-standard special case semantics would make sense for `Thread` in particular when they are not applied to anything else. I think @raxacoricofallapatorius would be better off to write their own `Thread` with this behavior than objecting too strongly to the existing function following the standard and generally expected evaluation sequence.

Comment: @OleksandrR.: Sorry, I wasn't trying to get anyone upset or make them feel threatened. See the actual question (and ChipHurst's answer, which addresses it).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius you didn't upset me or make me feel threatened and I hope I didn't to you either. You can criticize the design of *Mathematica* as much as you like, but the point I had intended was: given that it has a particular design, it's generally better for built-in functions to consistently follow that rather than each having their own special semantics. If a user-defined function with non-standard evaluation is desired, there are tools provided within the language to construct that.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius take `t[h_[args__List]] := MapThread[h, {args}]` and `x = {1, 2, 3} == {a, b, c}`. Now `t[x]` threads like `Thread` but using `MapThread`. You can make the "converse" function as well.

Comment: @ChipHurst: Can you copy this answer over to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102097/37)? I'm going to delete this one, it has attracted to much negative energy and misapprehension from the folks that don't like to see MMA criticized.