# Thread Part ([[]]) over two lists

Tags: list-manipulation

When I try to `Thread` `Part` function over two nested arrays, the operation is performed as expected but i get a warning. I'm not sure if (and what) am I doing wrong. The code example is below.

```
lst1 = {{5, -9, 15}, {12, -15, 4}}
indices={{2,1,3},{1,3,2}}
Thread[Part[lst1,indices]]
```

and the output is

```
{{-9, 5, 15}, {12, 4, -15}}
```

as expected. However, the following warning was thrown.

```
Part::pkspec1: The expression {{2,1,3},{1,3,2}} cannot be used as a part specification. >>
```

Shouldn't `Part` be threaded over the list as described in the help under `Thread` function?

Comment: `MapThread[Part, {lst1, indices}]`...

Comment: sometimes I use this kind of syntax : `Thread[myPart[lst1,indices]] /. myPart -> Part`. I don't know if it is a good practise.

Comment: @andre, yeah, that also seams plausible solution. But RunnyKine offered a neat solution which tackle the core of the problem.

Comment: Related: [(4390)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4390/121)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RunnyKine already explained in detail the source of the message.  I would like to offer a couple of alternative formulations of a solution and comment on your attempt to use `Hold`.

You commented:

> I tried `Thread[Hold[Part[lst1,indices]]]//ReleaseHold`. Apparently placed `Hold` at wrong place.

Indeed, for two reasons.

1. In this expression `Hold` is the active head of the argument of `Thread` so, if it were possible, *it* is the head that would be distributed:

   ```
   Thread[Hold[{1, 2, 3}]]
   ```

   > ```
   > {Hold[1], Hold[2], Hold[3]}
   > ```
2. For `Thread` to operate it must see explicit arguments at second level of the expression.  `Hold` here prevents `lst1` and `indices` from evaluating to their full forms therefore even if (1) is solved a problem remains.  To illustrate this we can use [`Unevaluated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unevaluated.html) which is like a temporary `Hold` that prevents evaluation but is transparent to the function in which it appears, i.e. `Thread`:

   ```
   Thread[Unevaluated[Part[lst1, indices]]]  (* Part::pkspec1 printed *)
   ```

RunnyKine's use of [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html) and andre's use of `Hold[Part]` each get around both these problems because:

1. They do not introduce an additional level in the expression; `Hold[Part]` is a compound head.

   ```
   TreeForm /@ {Hold[head[1, 2]], Hold[head][1, 2]}
   ```

   [image]
2. While `Part` is rendered inactive the arguments of the compound head still evaluate in the default manner therefore `lst1` and `indices` are expanded.

Another way to temporarily inactivate `Part` is [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html):

```
Block[{Part}, Thread @ lst1[[indices]] ]
```

But as already demonstrated by ciao (rasher) this kind of inhibition is not needed as [`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html) allows exactly the evaluation you want: expansion of `lst1` and `indices` before `Part` is applied and evaluated.

Comment: @Mr.Wizadr Suggestion: Perhaps you can consider expanding on this topic and adding one section to this post [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/34848) about most common pitfalls. Grasping hold of these evaluation order was already difficult let alone when one includes _pure functions_ and `Hold` constructs.

Comment: @ercegovac Indeed, the evaluation sequence in Mathematica is quite a beast, but understanding it is essential for any of the more advanced things. Mr.W +1 quite the scholarly summary.

Answer (score 10):

To understand what is going on here let's do the same evaluation with a symbol with no value and monitor it with `Trace`:

```
Remove[f];
Thread[f[lst1, indices]] // Trace

(*

{{{lst1, {{5,-9,15}, {12,-15,4}}}, {indices, {{2,1,3}, {1,3,2}}},
 f[{{5,-9,15},{12,-15,4}}, {{2,1,3}, {1,3,2}}]}, Thread[f[{{5,-9,15}, 
 {12,-15,4}}, {{2,1,3},{1,3,2}}]], {f[{5,-9,15}, {2,1,3}], f[{12,-15,4}, {1,3,2}]}}

*)
```

Here we see that `indices` was evaluated before being passed to `f`, so the error occurs before `Thread` gets its inputs. Now replace `f` with `Part` and you see the reason for the error. `Part` does not accept a list of lists as input only a 1D list is supported. To get around this, you can temporarily make `Part` inactive, do the evaluation then activate it as follows:

```
Thread[Inactive[Part][lst1, indices]] // Activate
```

> {{-9, 5, 15}, {12, 4, -15}}

as expected with no error messages. There are other ways to achieve the same thing, we can use `f` as described and later replace `f` with `Part`.

Comment: Thank you @RunnyKine. I suspected that to be problem but instead of `Activate` i was trying `Hold` which did not work. Though I am still novice in Mathematica...

Comment: @ercegovac `Thread[Hold[Part][lst1,indices]] //ReleaseHold` works fine !

Comment: @andre Thanks! I tried `Thread[Hold[Part[lst1,indices]]]//ReleaseHold`. Apparently placed `Hold` at wrong place.