# Inconsistent behavior of thread on empty llists

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider the following:

```
Quit[]
Thread[g[{1, 2}, 3]]
(* {g[1, 3], g[2, 3]} *)

Thread[g[{}, 3]]
(* {} *)
```

This works similarly if instead $g$ takes only one parameter. Now look at the following:

```
Quit[]
f1[x_] := x+3;
f2[x_,y_] := x + y + {1,0};

Thread[f1[{1,2}]]
(* {4, 5} *)
Thread[f1[{}]]
(* {} *)

Thread[f2[{1,2},5]]
(* {7, 7} *)
Thread[f2[{},5]]
(* Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in {}+5+{1,0} cannot be combined. *)
(* Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in 5+{}+{1,0} cannot be combined. *)
(* 5 + {} + {1, 0} *)
```

All of these make sense except for the last one. If threading works on $f1$ with an empty list, why shouldn't it work on $f2$ with an empty list?

(BTW, there was no tag for threading.)

Comment: Related (possibly duplicate): [(4390)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4390/121), [(135909)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/135909/121)

Comment: one fix is to define `f2` so that it can not accept a list as an argument , eg `f2[x_?AtomQ, y_] := x + y + {1, 0}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message you see *does not* come from `Thread` but instead from the failed application of the [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) Attribute of [`Plus`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plus.html).

```
f2[{}, 5];
```

> Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in {}+5+{1,0} cannot be combined. >>

`Listable` does not work over empty lists in the way that `Thread` does, despite the message name being `Thread::tdlen`:

```
Attributes[foo] = Listable;

foo[{}, {1, 2, 3}]
```

> Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in foo[{},{1,2,3}] cannot be combined. >>
>
> ```
> foo[{}, {1, 2, 3}]
> ```

If you want `Thread` to work in the example you give you'll need to control evaluation, e.g.

```
Thread[Unevaluated @ f2[{}, 5]]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

Comment: OK, but if $g$ is undefined, `Thread` doesn't even invoke $g$ when handed an empty list (or so it looks to me).

Comment: @rogerl It's an evaluation thing; I added one more example that I hope is enlightening?  `Thread[g[{}, 3]]` works precisely *because* `g` is undefined, i.e. it does not evaluate before `Thread` sees it.

Comment: Well, I see that using `Unevaluated` works, but I really don't see why. I kind of assumed that the argument to `Thread` was unevaluated anyway, since `Thread` needs to pick the expression apart.

Comment: @rogerl Please see the **Related** links (or now the **Linked** sidebar) I just added above.  I believe your questions will be answered therein.  If not feel free to ask more. :-)

Comment: OK, thanks. Feel free to close as duplicate if you think it is. Sorry I didn't find them myself.

Comment: @rogerl I am not voting to close as a duplicate as I do not believe either of those questions remarks upon the difference between `Listable` and `Thread` regarding `{}`.

Comment: I see. The real issue is (as @george279 pointed out in his comment) that `f2` does not restrict its argument type, so that both `{1,2}` and `{}` are simply passed into `f2`, and the threading doesn't actually take place. Now I see why your approach as well as the approach in the comment both work. Please tell me if I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: @rogerl That sounds right to me.