# How can I change elements in a matrix to a combination of other elements?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, function-construction

Suppose I have a list like

```
{
 {x1,y1,z1},
 {x2,y2,z2},
 {x3,y3,z3},
 ...
}
```

and I want to change it to

```
{
 {x1+Cos[z1/x1],y1,z1-Sin[z1/x1]},
 {x2+Cos[z2/x2],y2,z2-Sin[z2/x2]},
 {x3+Cos[z3/x3],y3,z3-Sin[z3/x3]},
 ...
}
```

What is the best way to do these matrix manipulations?

Comment: `{#[[1]]+Cos[#[[2]]/#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]] - Sin[#[[3]]/#[[1]]]]}& /@  list`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simple way would be to define a function to transform a single triple:

```
transform[{x_, y_, z_}] := {x + Cos[z/x], y, z - Sin[z/x]}
```

and then map it over your list:

```
transform /@ list
```

Answer (score 9):

```
{#1+Cos[#3/#1],#2,#3-Sin[#3/#1]}&@@@lst


(* {
    {x1 + Cos[z1/x1], y1, z1 - Sin[z1/x1]}, 
    {x2 + Cos[z2/x2], y2, z2 - Sin[z2/x2]}, 
    {x3 + Cos[z3/x3], y3, z3 - Sin[z3/x3]}
   } *)
```

In addition, using [`Inner`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inner.html):

```
Inner[Times, lst, {1,1,1},{#1+Cos[#3/#1], #2,#3-Sin[#3/#1]}&]==%

(* True *)
```

Or, using [`MapThread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html):

```
MapThread[{#1+Cos[#3/#1], #2,#3-Sin[#3/#1]}&,Transpose@lst]==%%

(* True *)
```

---

Just for fun: `MapThread`:

[`MapThread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html) may be used to apply a function to each *column* of a matrix.

```
MapThread[f,lst]

(* {
    f[x1, x2, x3], 
    f[y1, y2, y3], 
    f[z1, z2, z3]
   } * )
```

(And unlike [`Thread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html), `MapThread` does not evaluate its argument before threading: see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4391/106))

But:

```
 MapThread[f@#&,lst]

 (* {f[x1], f[y1], f[z1]} *)
```

```
MapThread[f@##&,lst]==MapThread[f,lst]

(* True *)
```

Therefore:

```
MapThread[{f@#1,g@#2,h@#3}&,lst]

(* {
    {f[x1], g[x2], h[x3]}, 
    {f[y1], g[y2], h[y3]}, 
    {f[z1], g[z2], h[z3]}
   } *)
```

```
MapThread[{f@#1,g@#2,h@#3}&,Transpose@lst]

(* {
    {f[x1], g[y1], h[z1]},
    {f[x2], g[y2], h[z2]}, 
    {f[x3], g[y3], h[z3]}
    } *)
```

```
lst 

(* {
    {x1, y1, z1}, 
    {x2, y2, z2}, 
    {x3, y3, z3}
   } *)
```

Answer (score 8):

Equivalent to @lericr`s answer except a pure function is used rather than defining a helper function

```
$Version

(* "13.3.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Using indexed variables formatted as subscripts

```
(Format[#[n_]] := Subscript[#, n]) & /@ {x, y, z};

list1 = Array[{x[#], y[#], z[#]} &, 4]
```

[image]

```
list2 = {#[[1]] + Cos[#[[3]]/#[[1]]], #[[2]], #[[3]] - Sin[#[[3]]/#[[1]]]} & /@
   list1
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Another way using `Cases`:

```
lst = {{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}, {x3, y3, z3}};

Cases[lst, {s1_, s2_, s3_} :> {s1 + Cos[s3/s1], s2, s3 - Sin[s3/s1]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Using `Replace`:**

```
amat = {{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}, {x3, y3, z3}};
Replace[amat, {x_, y_, z_} -> {x + Cos[z/x], y, z - Sin[z/x]}, 1]
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \cos \left(\frac{\text{z1}}{\text{x1}}\right)+\text{x1} & \text{y1} & \text{z1}-\sin \left(\frac{\text{z1}}{\text{x1}}\right) \\
 \cos \left(\frac{\text{z2}}{\text{x2}}\right)+\text{x2} & \text{y2} & \text{z2}-\sin \left(\frac{\text{z2}}{\text{x2}}\right) \\
 \cos \left(\frac{\text{z3}}{\text{x3}}\right)+\text{x3} & \text{y3} & \text{z3}-\sin \left(\frac{\text{z3}}{\text{x3}}\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$